# How to integrate Apache Calcite with Apache Cassandra and Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, cassandra, apache-calcite

I wish to integrate Apache Calcite as a library or server on top of Apache Cassandra database and use it as SQL datasource in Hibernate ORM or any other JPA implementation.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick browse of the Apache Calcite website shows that a [Cassandra adapter](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/cassandra_adapter.html) exists which allows you to query Cassandra with Calcite.

Have a look at the documentation which has an example and details. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I was aware about that. I want to know if I can use it as datasource in Hibernate or JPA ORM framework.